# Samsung TouchWiz crashes, when app with Nougat's Shortcut feature is installed

Tags: android, crash, samsung-touchwiz

I and my friends have made [Fling contact share app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phoenix.fling) and even published it on Playstore. We have added the [App shortcut feature](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html) in the app. We have tested it on many phones but when we install the app on Samsung phones the TouchWiz UI crashes continuously. I read a post that said TouchWiz does not support Shortcut feature. The thing is we have tested this app on Jellybean devices too without any problem.
Any suggestions on what to do and one more thing if there is any other error please do share.